# Variable won't resolve inside PL-SQL statement

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am trying to pass a SQL command to the SQL*Plus command-line program (Oracle) in my KornShell (ksh) script, but my `$MY_VAR` variable seems to be failing to resolve. `$MY_VAR` is a string value.

```
sqlplus -s << EOF >> $LOG_FILE
  $MY_SCHEMA
  UPDATE my_table SET run_flag = 'I', start_time = to_char(sysdate, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') WHERE (process_id = '$MY_VAR' AND run_flag != 'F');
  COMMIT;
EOF
```

I can successfully `echo` out the `$MY_VAR` variable, and so I can see that the variable is populated, but it does not seem to be resolving when inserting the variable into the SQL command which I am providing as an argument to the SQL*Plus program. The log file for the script simply outputs:

> 0 rows updated. Commit complete.

The SQL seems to be valid as we can successfully execute the command in SQL Developer (albeit with a hardcoded value for `$MY_VAR`).

Any ideas on what I am missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe, try removing quotes around variable name?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the variable is a string value, and the data type of the process_id is a CHAR(5). If I remove the single quotes won't it be treated like a number, and thus throw an error since the column type is a string? I'll give it a try though.

Comment: Gave it a try there, got the same error on removing the single quotes around the variable.

Comment: Variables don't get expanded inside single quotes. Use double quotes instead (i.e. `"$MY_VAR"`). If, alternatively, the single quotes are significant to the SQL, escape them so the shell doesn't look at them (i.e. `\'$MY_VAR\'`).

Comment: @twalberg, these single quotes are contained within a heredoc, so they're effectively inside double quotes. Thus, the single quotes are mere characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sql="$MY_SCHEMA
  UPDATE my_table SET run_flag = 'I', start_time = to_char(sysdate, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') WHERE (process_id = '$MY_VAR' AND run_flag != 'F');
  COMMIT;"
print "$sql"
sqlplus -s <<<"$sql" >> $LOG_FILE
```

Does the sql look correct? If it does and zero rows are updated, your where clause must be selecting zero rows.

Your version of ksh may not have the `<<<` here-string syntax. In that case:

```
print "$sql" | sqlplus -s >> $LOG_FILE
```